# Expose UserControl property to XAML

Tags: wpf, properties, user-controls

WPF controls have certain properties (UserControl.Resources, UserControl.CommandBindings) that can have items added to them from the XAML of a user control declaration. Example:

```
<UserControl ... >
  <UserControl.CommandBindings>
    ...
  </UserControl.CommandBindings>

  <UserControl.Resources>
    ...
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

I have a new list property defined in my user control:

```
public partial class ArchetypeControl : UserControl {
  ...
  public List<Object> UICommands { get; set; }
```

I want to add items to this list like I can with resources and CommandBindings, but when I do this:

```
<c:ArchetypeControl.UICommands>

</c:ArchetypeControl.UICommands>
```

I get the error "Error  4   The attachable property 'UICommands' was not found in type 'ArchetypeControl'. "

Suggestions?

### -

Given the comments, I've created a test control to show the entire code and reproduce the problem. I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ArchetypesUI.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ArchetypesUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <c:TestControl.TestObject>

    </c:TestControl.TestObject>

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

-

```
namespace ArchetypesUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
    {
        public Object TestObject { get; set; }

        public TestControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the error I get is "Error   2   The attached property 'TestControl.TestObject' is not defined on 'UserControl' or one of its base classes."

Comment: Works fine for me in VS2010... which version are you using ? BTW, you need to initialize the list in code or you won't be able to add items to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at your XAML:

```
<UserControl>
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
    <c:TestControl.TestObject>
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
    </c:TestControl.TestObject>
</UserControl>
```

Here, you are declaring a UserControl, and then trying to set a TestControl property on it.  Since UserControl doesn't have the TestControl.TestObject property, WPF that it can't set that property on the UserControl object.  You may say, "But I'm declaring a UserControl of type TestControl.  My UserControl *is* a TestControl!"  But that's not quite the case.  The above declaration is declaring the TestControl *class*: it's not creating an *instance* of TestControl, so it can't have instance properties set on it.

Rather, the TestObject property is there for *users* of TestControl to set on individual instances of TestControl:

```
<local:TestControl>
  <local:TestControl.TestObject>  <!-- Now it will work -->
  </local:TestControl.TestObject>
</local:TestControl>
```

If you want to set a default / initial value for the TestObject property, then you can do so either in the TestControl constructor, or (if TestObject is a dependency property) through the TestControl default style (though this is more for custom controls than for user controls).

Comment: How would this work is TestObject was a just a simple string and you just wanted to set it in XAML?

Comment: I believe in that case users could write `<local:TestControl TestObject="someString" />` - I think WPF will treat a literal value as a string rather than trying to convert it to some other type. Not tested though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite able to recreate your issue... the case I've created seems to work.  I did have to initialize the list in the constructor.

However, from your example I wonder a more appropriate place for your list source would be on a ViewModel object of some sort.  If you're exposing commands, having an IEnumerable of some sort of a ICommand wrapper which also encapsulates the display elements you need (e.g. Caption, Icon URI, etc).

ViewModels are certainly not a panacea, but in this case I think it would let you put all the knowledge of the commands you want to use in the same place (e.g. which are available and what they do).