# Bind Dependency Property, defined in Code-Behind, through Xaml to a Property in the DataContext of a UserControl

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface, binding

I want to use code similar to that found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404080/expose-usercontrol-property-to-xaml) The issue I'm having is that I'd like to extend it to allow the value set in the XAML to use `{Binding PropertyOfViewModel}` like this:

```
<local:TestControl>
  <local:TestControl.TestObject>
    {Binding PropertyOfViewModel}
  </local:TestControl.TestObject>
</local:TestControl>
```

The problem, is that it errors with "Cannot Convert "{Binding PropertyOfViewModel}"". The TestObject property is defined as a dependency property in the code-behind of the view.

If I can get it to work, this will allow me to write code like this in the parent control:

```
<local:TestControl x:Name="myControl" DataContext="{Binding TCViewModel}" />
```

Which means in the UserControl I can also bind to commands and other items exposed in my TCViewModel, and the control can be mostly self-contained, and all a consumer need to is set the DataContext property.

---

**edit**

This is the entire control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.AddClientView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
         Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<!-- Comment out from here
   <Views:AddClientView>
    <Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
    <Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>
        <Binding Path="IsInInputMode"/>
    </Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>
    <Views:AddClientView.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
to here -->
            <Grid>
                <Label 
                    Height="25" 
                    Width="306"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Margin="12,12,0,0" 
                    OverridesDefaultStyle="False" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource CalloutLabel}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Company Name (Name of Organizational Unit)"/>

                <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,41,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" />

                <Button 
                    Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
                    Height="23" Width="75" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                    Margin="0,0,97,12" 
                    TabIndex="4">OK</Button>

                <Button 
                    Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
                    Height="23" Width="75" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                    Margin="0,0,12,12" 
                    Command="{Binding Cancel}"
                    TabIndex="3">Cancel</Button>

                <CheckBox Content="Make Groups" Height="16" IsChecked="True" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="150,79,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="2" />

                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource HeaderBarFill}" Height="5" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
            </Grid>
<!-- and here 
        </DataTemplate>
    </Views:AddClientView.ContentTemplate>
</Views:AddClientView>
to here-->
```

In order to get it to compile with the code suggested, I had to re-arrange my xaml, now it both crashes Visual Studio in Design Mode, and when I run it, I get a StackOverflow exception on `InitializeComponent();` in the Views Constructor.

---

**edit 2**

This is the code that puts this UserControl on the window:

```
<Views:AddClientView x:Name="AddClient" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding AddClientVM}">
</Views:AddClientView>
```

Interestingly: if I remove this code from the Window, it runs/compiles OK. If I remove all of the `<Views:AddClientView...>` type code from within the View, it also runs OK. But does not do what I want because I cannot bind my DP to the DataContext.

If I change the UserControl to the below, everything compiles fine, I just loose the binding on my code-behind dependency property:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Mage.Views.AddClientView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Mage.Views"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignWidth="320" d:DesignHeight="145"
    x:Name="AddClientV"
    MaxHeight="145" MinHeight="145">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Show">
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="AddClientV" 
                            From="0" 
                            To="1" 
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Hide">
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="AddClientV" 
                        From="1" 
                        To="0" 
                        Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Views:AddClientView>
        <Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
        </Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
        <Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>
            <Binding Path="IsInInputMode"/>
        </Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>
        <Views:AddClientView.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label 
                        Height="25" 
                        Width="306"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Margin="12,12,0,0" 
                        OverridesDefaultStyle="False" 
                        Style="{DynamicResource CalloutLabel}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Company Name (Name of Organizational Unit)"/>

                    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,41,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" />

                    <Button 
                        Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
                        Height="23" Width="75" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        Margin="0,0,97,12" 
                        TabIndex="4">OK</Button>

                    <Button 
                        Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
                        Height="23" Width="75" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                        Margin="0,0,12,12" 
                        Command="{Binding Cancel}"
                        TabIndex="3">Cancel</Button>

                    <CheckBox Content="Make Groups" Height="16" IsChecked="True" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="150,79,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="2" />

                    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource HeaderBarFill}" Height="5" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Views:AddClientView.ContentTemplate>
    </Views:AddClientView>
</UserControl>
```

Code-Behind Dependency Property:

```
    public bool IsInAcceptDataMode
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInAcceptDataModeProperty); }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(IsInAcceptDataModeProperty, value); 

            if (value)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Show", false);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Hide", false);
            }
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInAcceptDataModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsInAcceptDataMode", typeof(bool), typeof(AddClientView), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, null));
```

---

**edit 3**

So I've been informed that there are issues with XAML based binding, I tried moving to code-behind, and I still cannot get it to work. So, I'm looking at this point for a code-behind based way to bind my DependencyProperty to an item in the ViewModel which is specified to the DataContext of my UserControl.

Comment: Could show the view that contains this UserControl? I haven't noticed any problems with the code you provided.

Comment: Where is your code-behind dependency property that you are talking about? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: Just updated to include the XAML for the user control and the code-behind DP.

Comment: BTW, your `IsInAcceptDataMode` is incorrect. This setter will not work with binding (it will not be invoked). You have to use dependency property callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood everything correctly then what you need is a standard MVVM scenario and standard bindings.

It can be done either like this:

```
<local:TestControl TestObject="{Binding PropertyOfViewModel}">
</local:TestControl>
```

Or like this:

```
<local:TestControl>
  <local:TestControl.TestObject>
    <Binding Path="PropertyOfViewModel"/>
  </local:TestControl.TestObject>
</local:TestControl>
```

**Update:** In response to the code of your `UserControl` you've shown...

What you are doing is placing a control inside itself, which obviously will give you a StackOverflow exception.
You don't need to define a `ContentTemplate` inside `UserControl`. You can just place the content directly as a child element:

```
<UserControl 
    x:Class="Mage.Views.AddClientView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Mage.Views"
    Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"  d:DesignWidth="320" d:DesignHeight="145"
    x:Name="AddClientV"
    MaxHeight="145" MinHeight="145">

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Show">
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="AddClientV" 
                            From="0" 
                            To="1" 
                            Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Hide">
                <VisualState.Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="AddClientV" 
                        From="1" 
                        To="0" 
                        Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState.Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
    </Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform>
    <Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>
            <Binding Path="IsInInputMode"/>
    </Views:AddClientView.IsInAcceptDataMode>

   <Grid>
      <Label 
        Height="25" 
        Width="306"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="12,12,0,0" 
        OverridesDefaultStyle="False" 
        Style="{DynamicResource CalloutLabel}" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Company Name (Name of Organizational Unit)"/>

    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="12,41,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="1" />

    <Button 
        Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
        Height="23" Width="75" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Margin="0,0,97,12" 
        TabIndex="4">OK</Button>

    <Button 
        Style="{DynamicResource LightButton}" 
        Height="23" Width="75" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
        Margin="0,0,12,12" 
        Command="{Binding Cancel}"
        TabIndex="3">Cancel</Button>

    <CheckBox Content="Make Groups" Height="16" IsChecked="True" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Margin="150,79,12,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="2" />

    <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource HeaderBarFill}" Height="5" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Adding that code gives me a StackOverflow exception when I run the project. I'm in-process of removing name specifcs from my control (its only a few lines) and I'll post the whole thing, maybe something else I have is conflicting and causing my problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending time on this. With the code you updated with, VS no longer crashes, and I no longer get StackOverflow.... but I had to remove the `Views:AddClientView..` code to get it to compile, the error is: The attachable property 'RenderTransform' was not found in type 'AddClientView'. -- and I get the same error for IsInAcceptDataMode. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Nate - Yeah... Just remembered that there is a known issue with specifying properties defined in custom user control from its XAML... You will not be able to do it. Instead you'll have to set this binding from code-behind, e.g. in the constructor: SetBinding(IsInAcceptDataModeProperty, "IsInInputMode"). As for RenderTransoform, just replace <Views:AddClientView.RenderTransform> with <UserControl.RenderTransform> and it should work.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out, any word on if/when it will be fixed?

Comment: No love with `SetBinding(IsInAcceptDataModeProperty, "IsInInputMode")` in the constructor, but I'm going to keep poking around.